# Why is Worf a yellow shirt in seasons 2-7 of Star Trek: The Next Generation?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

In seasons 2-7, Worf wears a yellow shirt as an operations officer while most other series have operations officers wearing red shirts.

Comment: I'm nitpicking here, but the term '[red shirt](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RedShirt)' usually refers to the red-shirted Starfleet security officers in _The Original Series_, who were notorious for getting killed a lot. By the time of _The Next Generation_, security officers like Tasha Yar wore yellow/gold instead of red, making them the spiritual equivalent of 'red shirts' in the _TNG_ era, and red-uniformed officers like Picard and Riker aren't generally considered to be 'red shirts' themselves.

Comment: [Why (out of universe) were the red and gold uniform colours in Star Trek swapped?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/275959/122024).

Comment: [When did the red shirt careers change to yellow shirts in Star Trek and why?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/4402/122024).

Comment: @Giacomo1968 - Judging by a comment they left in the [revision history](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/283241/revisions) of this question, it appears the OP now wants to know why the Starfleet uniform colours for the operations and command divisions were switched in _TNG_. That is a different question to the one originally asked, but it too has been asked and answered before, as evident by the links I posted in my last two comments,